# there aren't many opportunities when/where/that I can practice my English

Tags: word-usage, relative-pronouns

I am wondering which is the correct form for this sentence

> There aren't many opportunities when/where/that I can practice my English.

plus, if I want to express I don't have lots time or chances to speak English in my daily life, what are some other ways to express this?

Answer (score 1):

I would say "when" but another way is

> There aren't many opportunities for me to practise my English.

Note the *British* spelling correction of **practice** (noun) to **practise** (verb). American English uses **practice** for both verb and noun forms.

Comment: I made an edit, as **practise** is the British spelling, and is in fact "incorrect" by American English standards.

Comment: @Tashus thank you but I think you mean British **English**. There is no language called "British" although I do sometimes refer to American English as **American**. I suppose it depends on where you are, not on how English developed.

Comment: I was using British as an adjective, not a noun.

Comment: Well, I love it when people tell me my native language is **incorrect**.

Comment: Likewise, you "corrected" the question in a way that only applies to your locality. I used scare quotes in my comment specifically to emphasize the issue.

Comment: I am sorry, I had no idea that our spelling had been forgotten.

Comment: It hadn't, hence I specified the difference rather than simply changing the British spelling to the American one. The question is not tagged as pertaining to British English exclusively.